# Trouble finding DataGrid to implement for over 10,000 records with pagination, filtering, and clickable links for each row

Tags: json, datagrid, yui

I have tried using a few different data grids (FlexiGrid, ExtJs Grid, and YUI DataGrid) and have found YUI to work the best as far as documentation and features available. However, I am having difficulty setting up the data source.  When I try to set it up using JSON, it takes too long, or times out.  I have already maxed out the memory usage in the php.ini file.  There will be many more records in the future as well.

I need to select data to populate the grid based on the user that is currently logged in.  Once this information populates the grid, I need each id to be click-able and take me to a different page, or populate information in a div on the same page.

Does anyone have suggestions on loading 25 – 50 records at a time of dynamic data? I have tried implementing the following example to do what I want: [YUI Developer Example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_dynamicdata_clean.html)
I cannot get the data grid to show at all.  I have changed the data instance to the following.

`// DataSource instance

var curDealerNumber = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName('dealer_number', 'input');

var ds_path =  + "lib/php/json_proxy.php?dealernumber='" + curDealerNumber + "'";

var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource("ds_path");

myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSON;

myDataSource.responseSchema = {

    resultsList: "records",

    fields: [

    {key:"id", parser:"number"},

    {key:"user_dealername"},

    {key:"user_dealeraccttype"},

    {key:"workorder_num", parser:"number"},

    {key:"segment_num", parser:"number"},

    {key:"status"},

    {key:"claim_type"},

    {key:"created_at"},

    {key:"updated_at"}

    ],
    metaFields: {

         totalRecords: "totalRecords" // Access to value in the server response

    }
};`

Any help is greatly appreciated, and sorry if this seems similar to other posts, but I searched and still could not resolve my problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to troubleshoot without a repro case, but I'd suggest turning on logging to see where the problem might be:

- load datatable-debug file
- load logger
- either call YAHOO.widget.Logger.enableBrowserConsole() to output logs to your browser's JS console (i.e., Firebug), or call new YAHOO.widget.LogReader() to output logs to the screen.

Also make sure the XHR request and response are well-formed with Firebug or similar tool.

Finally, when working with large datasets, consider

- pagination
- enabling renderLoopSize (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/#renderLoop)
- chunking data loads into multiple requests (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_xhrjson.html).

There is no one-size-fits-all solution for everyone, but hopefully you can find the right set of tweaks for your use case.